# Opening a .NET sdt file (serialized datatable) in Ruby

Tags: .net, ruby, datatable

I'm making a call out to a service which returns .sdt files. 
I need to be able to open them, and validate some data.

This portion is a part of a bigger Ruby project, so I need to be able to do this using Ruby.
Does anyone know how I can go about opening an .sdt file, to some format I can use in ruby?
Maybe convert it to xml, or JSON, just something that I can parse through.

Comment: could you point to the documentation of this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eneded up writing a SDT to JSON converter in .NET, making use of this library: [json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Once I got an executable built, I made a call out to it in Ruby and had it generate the JSON files for me. At which point, I should be able to load up the files in memory via Ruby.